# Chrome proxy api - Uncaught TypeError: Invalid invocation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I want to use the chrome proxy API. I have this code in my background script but it will not work

```
const proxyData = []

const fetchProxyData = () => {
  axios({
    method: "GET",
    baseURL: "https://api.getproxylist.com/proxy",
    params: {
      protocol: "http",
      allowsPost: 1,
      allowsHttps: 1,
      anonimity: "high anonymity"
    }
  }).then( (response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    proxyData.push(response.data)
  })
}

fetchProxyData();

var config = {
  mode: "fixed_servers",
  rules: {
    singleProxy: {
      host: proxyData.ip,
      port: proxyData.port
    }
  }
}

chrome.proxy.settings.set({
   value: config,
   scope: "regular"
 }, () => {
   console.log(`proxy configured with data: ${proxyData}`)
})
```

I get this error in background page console: `background.js:55 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid invocation`

I've tried with the example provided with the proxy api documentation and the error will not occur. Maybe it's caused by the config object? To set the proxy as you can see in the code, I'm using an ajax call, maybe is this the problem?

is there any fix?

Comment: Which of the lines is "_55_"?

Comment: it's the `chrome.proxy.settings.set({})` function.

Comment: Typo: `anonimity` should be `anonymity`

Comment: @nukiko12 do you get any solution for this error?

Comment: Hi, I met the same thing and found on the doc page of `chrome.proxy` API, it says `only works in Chrome OS` now... I didn't buy it at first, because I saw so many proxy extensions are still available in the store, but then I saw in one of the extension talking about [a change from v53](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=619097), not sure it is only affecting the PAC script or all the proxy APIs

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same problem when I find the solution, it was silly mistake.

I had passed string value to `port`.

Please make sure you are passing integer value to `port`

Answer (score 0):

Close. Couple things.

One, you need to fetch your data before calling Chrome's proxy API. And two, your getting the properties for your config from the `proxyData` array, not the JSON object from your axios call.

You need to do something like this:

```
const proxyData = [];
const fetchProxyData = () => {
    axios({
        method: "GET",
        baseURL: "https://api.getproxylist.com/proxy",
        params: {
            protocol: "http",
            allowsPost: 1,
            allowsHttps: 1,
            anonimity: "high anonymity"
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        const {data} = response;

        proxyData.push(data);

        const config = {
            mode: "fixed_servers",
            rules: {
                singleProxy: {
                    host: data.ip,
                    port: data.port
                }
            }
        };

        chrome.proxy.settings.set({
            value: config,
            scope: "regular"
        }, () => {
            console.log(`proxy configured with data: ${data}`)
        });
    })
};

fetchProxyData();
```

What's happening with your code...The properties `host` and `port` in `singleProxy` (in `config`) are being assigned `undefined` because those properties don't exist in the array `proxyData`. They exist in the object returned from your axios call (above, `data`).

The `undefined` keys caused Chrome to throw an Invalid Invocation error.

For anyone else getting the Invalid Invocation issue, it seems to me the problem usually lies within the config your passing into Chrome. In particular the types of each key.

In my case, I was passing in the port as a string when it needed to be a number.